# disappearing row names when using apply

Tags: sorting, r, apply

Consider the following example (values in vectors are target practice results and I'm trying to automagically sort by shooting score). We generate three vectors. We sort values in columns `1:20` in ascending order and rows in descending order based on `out.tot` column.

```
# Generate data
shooter1 <- round(runif(n = 20, min = 1, max = 10))
shooter2 <- round(runif(n = 20, min = 1, max = 10))
shooter3 <- round(runif(n = 20, min = 1, max = 10))
out <- data.frame(t(data.frame(shooter1, shooter2, shooter3)))
colnames(out) <- 1:ncol(out)

out.sort <- t(apply(out, 1, sort, na.last = FALSE))
out.tot <- apply(out , 1, sum)
colnames(out.sort) <- 1:ncol(out.sort)
out2 <- cbind(out.sort, out.tot)

out3 <- apply(out2, 2, sort, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = FALSE)
```

`out2` has row names attached while `out3` lost them. The only difference is that I used `MARGIN = 2`, which is probably the culprit (because it takes in column by column). I can match rows by hand, but is there a way I can keep row names in `out3` from disappearing?

```
> out2
         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 out.tot
shooter1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5  5  6  6  6  6  6  7  8  9  9 10     106
shooter2 1 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5  5  5  5  5  6  7  8  8  9  9 10     107
shooter3 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5  5  5  6  6  6  6  7  8  8  8  9      97

> out3
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 out.tot
[1,] 1 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5  5  6  6  6  6  7  8  8  9  9 10     107
[2,] 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5  5  5  6  6  6  6  7  8  9  9 10     106
[3,] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5  5  5  5  5  6  6  7  8  8  8  9      97
```

Comment: Your problem is the transpose. When you transpose, it drops the row names and converts to a matrix.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. If I run the code, the row.names are still there for out.sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your example, going from `out2` to `out3` you are sorting each column independently - meaning that the values on row 1 may not all come from the data generated from shooter1. It makes sense then that the rownames are dropped in as much as rownames are names of observations and you are no longer keeping data from one observation on one row.